# Python 2.7 fnmatch NOT editing text

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, fnmatch

I have a file with 600k+ records of string labels I am trying to edit with an update cursor using both the string modules and fnmatch to find patterns to edit. The section using fnmatch is successfully printing the matched records but not changing / parsing out the matched pattern.

There is no error and there is no change to the record. What am I missing with my syntax?

(Also - side issue, the last print row 4 statement only prints the first record of the file.)

The result samples are unchanged from original text
1000STR92SE
8000STR37NW
7000STR35SW
8000STR44
1000STR88SE
1000STR74SE

But results need to be
92SE
37NW
35SW
44
88SE
74SE

```
def newlabel():
#Global Conversions - works on editing the string
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(mvum_fc, newfields) as uc:
        for row in uc:
            if row[1] == None or row[1].startswith('0'):
                row[4] = '{}'.format(row[4].lstrip(ascii_letters).replace('_', "-").lstrip('0').replace(' ', '-'))

            if row[1] == None or row[1].startswith('-'):
                row[4] = '{}'.format(row[4].lstrip('-').lstrip('0'))
#Regional Conversions - lstrip and replace tried - not changing text.
            elif row[1].startswith('0118'):
                pattern = ('?000STR*')
                match = fnmatch.fnmatch(row[4], pattern)
                if match == True:
                    row[4] = '{}'.format(row[4].lstrip('?000STR'))
                    print(row[4])
            uc.updateRow(row)
            print(row[4])
```

Comment: Please show a [mre].

Comment: @mkrieger1 - Does this clarify? Can you provide help?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `?` in the string you want to strip. It is a wildcard used in pattern matching.

```
row[4] = '{}'.format(row[4].lstrip('000STR'))
```

Comment: I need to use the wildcard since the data could be 1000STR or 2000STR - etc.

Comment: lstrip() does not work with wildcards. It strips the exact string we provide as input. You will have to do the pattern matching separately to give it the correct input

Comment: Thanks, for the response. Do you have an alternative suggestion to use wildcards with? I have over half a million records so using a wildcard with the pattern match is pretty important.

Comment: You can try regex:  `row[4]= re.sub( '.000STR' , "" , row[4] )`

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this by avoiding the .lstrip:

row[4] = '{}'.format(row[4].lstrip('000STR'))

and simply replacing it with:

row[4] = '{}'.format(row[4][7:])